# running a derby database folder as a remote DB

Tags: java, database, derby

I have a derby database folder. I am using the database with my java app with the URL:
"jdbc:derby:C\enterprisedb", "user", "pass";

Now I need to make this database remote so that it can be accessed from remote computers also. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Derby, but the documentation suggests that it can run in a standard client/server mode.

So you should follow [these instructions](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html) for starting a Derby network server, eventually ending up with:

```
java -jar derbyrun.jar server start
```

(on the server).

Then from your client, use a JDBC URL of something like

```
"jdbc:derby://yourserver:1527/enterprisedb"
```

Comment: Actually that can be done when you enable the server. I'm not using the server here. Java can use the derby database by just providing the database folder location. 
I want to convert this database into online database.

Comment: For eg., it do the above thing, it will definitely start the derby server but I won't be able to contact my enterprisedb lying on C:\ from remote conections.

Comment: @SudheeraMinocha: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand your comments at all. But I'm suggesting you *should* use the server, as documented in the linked page. The server should be on the machine with the database. You then need to connect to that server, and it will be able to serve that database.